# WriteLine over multiple lines with multiple values

Tags: c#

trying to understand!!

```
string myValue1 = "1";
string myValue2 = "2";

Console.WriteLine(myValue1, myValue2);
```

This only prints out the first value, if one use + the it concatenates them together. is there a way to have the two values printed on separate lines.
I can use two WriteLines (one for each Value) but I am trying to be more efficient (or Stupid)!!

Comment: Your code doesn't compile, also how you are passing values to `Console.WriteLine` ??

Comment: Two writelines is fine.  Other solutions are just a micro-optimization that won't give any noticeable results in the real world.

Comment: they are just strings and I wanted to see if I am on the write track by using two writelines or if there was a way to use one writeline to do the same things for 2 values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Environment.NewLine` for printing values on different lines. Use [`Console.WriteLine Method (String, Object[])` overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/828t9b9h%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which takes a string format and values.

```
Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}{2}", myValue1, Environment.NewLine, myValue2);
```

If this is a single statement, than I really doubt if it will give you any performance gain.

Comment: thanks for this. it made this overload easier to get my head around and I did not think of it this way.

Answer (score 3):

You are using the format overload [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/828t9b9h(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/828t9b9h%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

This one supports placeholders {0}, {1}... The first argument is the format and the subsequent arguments are put in the placeholder. Because your string does not have any placeholders the second value is missing. For what you want to do you'd best just call WriteLine twice.

```
Console.WriteLine(myValue1);
Console.WriteLine(myValue2);
```

Concatenating new line will make your code harder to read. Don't try to be efficient this way. It is stupid :)

Comment: Any gains made in 'efficiency' will be offset by the lower readability of the code. It is more 'efficient' to write code that is easier to read.

Comment: This computes in my head for this example and is easy.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a [verbatim string literal `@`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim) and it will look like that:

```
    Console.WriteLine(@"{0}
{1}", myValue1, myValue2);
```

The output will be on separate lines.  However, in my opinion the c# doesn't look well written.

Answer (score 1):

concat an Environment.NewLine    //

Answer (score 0):

If by efficient you mean write less code you can do this:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        WriteMultiLine(1,2, "hello", TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static void WriteMultiLine(params object[] values)
    {
        foreach (var value in values)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(value);
        }
    }
```

You can print whatever you want on different lines.

The output is:

```
1
2
hello
00:03:00
```

Comment: how? it would be if you copy paste it in every class. Otherwise it's a single line like the example given with the format with the difference that the one with the format is harder to write and its probably harder to understand

Comment: Well sure, but the example was just two values so this is probably overkill. Not saying it's a bad helper function, just saying it's not shorter all together.

Comment: @MattJohnson Ok, if that's the real use case and not a simplification by the OP I agree,it is better to have two sequential WriteLine. But still it might be useful to someone looking for the same question.